# Unable to install docker on AWS Linux AMI

Tags: docker, amazon-ami

I followed the steps to install `docker` on my `EC2` instance which is based on `Amazon AMI` using the instructions from the official link - [official docker installation on centos](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/). I am getting the below error.

```
$ sudo yum update
........
$ sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
........
-------->  Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: have you ran 'yum update'

Comment: @VikrantPawar yes. I have run the `sudo yum update` before installing docker

Comment: Try this yum --nogpgcheck localinstall docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

Comment: No luck:

    sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall docker-ce docker-ce -cli containerd.io
    Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
    Skipping: docker-ce, filename does not end in .rpm.
    Skipping: docker-ce-cli, filename does not end in .rpm.
    Skipping: containerd.io, filename does not end in .rpm.
    Nothing to do

Comment: @zilcuanu were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @zilcuanu I have the same problem.Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solution in context of the image - **Amazon Linux 2 AMI**

One may need to remove the packages they installed using docker provided links

use the command here to remove all of that:-

`sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo`

And use the link given by AWS to install the docker [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

The content for that commands in that link are as below:-

Connect to your instance(Amazon Linux 2 AMI).

1. Update the installed packages and package cache on your instance.

   `sudo yum update -y`
2. Install the most recent Docker Community Edition package.

   `sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker`
3. Start the Docker service.

   `sudo service docker start`
4. Add the ec2-user to the docker group so you can execute Docker commands without using sudo.

   `sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user`
5. Log out and log back in again to pick up the new docker group permissions. You can accomplish this by closing your current SSH terminal window and reconnecting to your instance in a new one. Your new SSH session will have the appropriate docker group permissions.
6. Verify that the ec2-user can run Docker commands without sudo.

   `docker info`

Answer (score 3):

Use **amazon-linux-extras** to install docker

```sh
# install
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo # if you have already tried in the wrong way
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker

# enable on boot and start daemon
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker

# correct permissions
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
newgrp docker
docker ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AMI best practices are to use their install procedures.  You, of course, are at your liberty to do what best fits your needs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

Figured it out because I had a similar issue an hour ago, and just realized I was doing it wrong:

https://serverfault.com/questions/836198/how-to-install-docker-on-aws-ec2-instance-with-ami-ce-ee-update

Answer (score 0):

I installed docker using below link. May this be helping others

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

[image]